# The sequence of functions $f_n=\frac{n}{1+n\sqrt{x}}$ in $L^1(0,1)$ and $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

During a lecture on $L^p$ spaces, the lecturer made a few comments about the sequence of functions  $f_n=\frac{n}{1+n\sqrt{x}}$ that I am not sure I fully understand.

1) First he said $f_n\in L^2(0,1)$:

I have $\int_0^1\frac{n^2}{1+2n\sqrt{x}+x}=n^2\int_0^1dmx+\frac{n}{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dmx+n^2\int^1_0\frac{1}{x}$. Now, the very last integral does not converge, so this doesn't seem to me to belong to $L^2(0,1)$, what am I missing?

2) Then his powerpoint presentation asked whether the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, belongs to either $L^2(0,1)$ or $L^1(0,1)$, or both.

Am I right in saying that it belongs to $L^1(0,1)$ but not $L^2(0,1)$ since the integral would converge in the first case and not in the second?

3) Then he asked to determine whether $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1(0,1)$ or $L^2(0,1)$.

Since $f$ is not in $L^2(0,1)$, the sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1(0,1)$. Is that all there is to this question?

4) Finally, he asked whether $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in either $L^2(0,1)$ or $L^1(0,1)$.

My understanding is that since all convergent sequences are Cauchy, $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^1(0,1)$, and since all $L^p$ spaces are complete (Banach), then not converging in $L^2(0,1)$ implies that $f_n$ is not Cauchy in $L^2(0,1)$

I know this is wordy, but I want to make sure I understand this stuff, any comments or insights are appreciated.

Comment: Re 1), because of the $1$ in the denominator, the functions $f_n$ are each bounded on $(0,1)$, indeed $\leq n$, and thus they belong to $L^1$ and $L^2$.

Comment: @ForgotALot thanks for your comment. So when I decompose the integral:$ \int_0^1\frac{n^2}{1+2n\sqrt{x}+x}=n^2\int_0^1dmx+\frac{n}{2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{ \sqrt{x}}dmx+n^2\int^1_0\frac{1}{x}$, am I wrong in saying that the last one does not converge?

Comment: You can't split up the sum in the denominator like you have. It's true that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx$ diverges, but that's irrelevant. Notice that for $x\in (0,1)$, $1+2n\sqrt{x}+n^2x \geq 1$ so 
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{n}{1+n\sqrt{x}}\right)^2 dx = \int_0^1\frac{n^2}{1+2n\sqrt{x}+n^2x} dx \leq \int_0^1 \frac{n^2}{1} dx = n^2.$$

Comment: @ForgotALot Bahhh I forgot that $n^2$... Thanks for the help!